# How to get images from Android to Ubuntu

Tags: android

I want to move files from my android phone to ubuntu with a script.

In the past I used this:

```
rsync -av  --remove-source-files android:/storage/F8D3-5FEF/DCIM/Camera/  .
```

And the SSHelper app.

But since I use LineageOS with Android 7.1.2, I get "permission denied" if rsync tries to remove the source file.

The "permission denied" message comes from the SSHelper (SSH server) on my android device.

Comment: Did you by any chance attempt using `sudo` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek the "permission denied" happens when rsync tries to delete a file on the remote (android) endpoint. I think running rsync with sudo on the local endpoint won't help.

Comment: The difference between thinking and knowing typically requires utilization of the scientific method. I suggest that you try it and [edit] your results into your post.